# How to write a Regex format to accept a query string and a date?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a query string with a datetime value and input of like "?sincemodified=2013-04-02T08:34:12Z".

How to write an optional Regex format to accept above?

I wrote the below but failed:

```
Regex.Match(@"?sincemodified=2013-04-02T08:34:12Z", @"^[\?sincemodified=\.*]?$").Success
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, you need to use Regex for this.

Just use this,

```
Request.QueryString["sincemodified"];
```

Another option is using **[HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring.aspx)**,

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("?sincemodified=2013-04-02T08:34:12Z").Get("sincemodified");
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you used is good just that you don't need to escape "."

regular expression could be

```
/\?sincemodified=.*/
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, REGEX is not a good idea to parse date values, instead use `DateTime.TryParse` like:

```
if(Request.QueryString["sincemodified"] != null)
{
   DateTime dt;
   if(DateTime.TryParse(Request.QueryString["sincemodified"], out dt)
     {
      //valid date
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

^: mean the beginning,
* :whatever character,
$ :mean the end of text ,

So you do not need to specify ^..*$ to say that you want what is in the beginning, just ^.. is sufficient, so :

```
Regex.Match(@"?sincemodified=2013-04-02T08:34:12Z", @"^\?sincemodified=").Success;
```

would be working

if you want something not empty after sincemodified here is an amelioration:

```
Regex.Match(@"?sincemodified=2013-04-02T08:34:12Z", @"^\?sincemodified=(?!\s*$).+").Success;
```